# How can I navigate to a different page based on which section of a pie chart I click using angular chart.js?

Tags: angular, chart.js, pie-chart

I am using chart.js for the Pie charts in angular. Now I have to click each pie and render my page according to that. Basically, I want to navigate to a different page so for that I have to know the event value like on which pie I have clicked.

```
>!HTML Code >! 
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <h3 class="doText text-center" >Health Data</h3>
    <div   id="pie">
      <canvas baseChart width="2" height="2" (click)="sampletest(Unlocked,Healthy,Unhealthy)"
        [data]="pieChartData"
        [labels]="pieChartLabels"
        [colors]="pieChartColors"
        [chartType]="pieChartType">
    </canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
>!TS Code >! 
  public pieChartLabels: Label[] = ['Unlocked', 'Healthy', 'Unhealthy'];
  public pieChartData: MultiDataSet = [
    [178, 150, 100],
    
  ];
 options:object = {

 }
  public pieChartColors: any[] =
    [
      {
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgb(147,203,254)',
          'rgb(53,152,237)',
          'rgb(215,195,255)',
        ]
      }
    ]
  public pieLables: any[] = [10, 22, 21];
  public pieChartType: ChartType = 'pie';[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKrUS.png)
```

I tried to write onclick in with the option but It won't work maybe I am not Integrating that in the correct way.
I want to approach and how to Integrate.